# NSDateFormatter bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

date = 2016-12-25 21:00:00 +0000

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateformat.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateformat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateStr:%@",dateString);
```

Log:

> dateStr:2017-12-26

My locale +3 hours

Is it a bug? Or a feature?

Comment: you need to change date format @"yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer bug.

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

`YYYY` is year in a week based calendar.

Comment: Thanks! Nice catch!